# Circle Geometry - What Information Given can help me find the other angles.

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I'm currently studying for a test in Grade 8 Honours Math (Grade 9). We have some questions involving Circle Geometry, but I'm having trouble here:

[image: Circle Geometry Question]

You see, I know the value of w due to it being an isosceles triangle, but I'm not sure how this relates to Angle x.

Many Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Is AD a diameter? Have you learned that a triangle drawn in a circle with two vertices at the opposite ends of a diameter is a right triangle?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales ahh, that makes sense. I see now, is point B was anywhere along the arc it would be a right triangle. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X must be a right angle because it faces a $180°$ arc. Therefore, $z=180-90-25=65°$.

What you have is correct. You know that y must be $90°$ because it also faces an $180°$ arc, and because triangle ACD is isosceles, W must be $\frac{180-90}{2}$ or $45°$.

Comment: $(180-90)/2=45°$.  Someone with 2k+ rep please correct if I can't get my edit through.

Comment: I’ve updated it.

Comment: Thanks, now it's all good +1.